# How can i add the macro in excel sheet using python?

Tags: python, excel, vba

> **This code writing macros in excel workbook but i need to write in excel sheet how can i do that ?  **

[image]

```
import win32com.client 
import os, sys
 
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
 
_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
path = os.path.dirname(_file)
 
# set file paths and macro name accordingly - here we assume that the files are located in the same folder as the Python script
pathToMacro = path + "/myMacro.txt"
myMacroName = "UsefulMacro"
 
# read the textfile holding the excel macro into a string
with open(pathToMacro, "r") as myfile:
    print("reading macro into string from: " + str(myfile))
    macro = myfile.read()

path = r"deneme.xlsm"
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(path)
wb.VBProject.VBComponents(1).CodeModule.AddFromString(macro)
wb.Close(True)
xl.Quit()
```

Comment: See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx for an overview of inserting code programmatically.

Comment: `wb.VBProject.VBComponents(1).Name` would return something like 'ThisWorkbook' and `wb.VBProject.VBComponents(2).Name` would return 'Sheet1' if that is the first Sheet in the workbook, etc So either check the name for the Sheet you want or if there is just one sheet then change it to `wb.VBProject.VBComponents(2).CodeModule.AddFromString(macro)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to get the `VBComponent` reference with name.

```py
import win32com.client 
import os, sys

# your code

path = r"D:/temp/deneme.xlsm"
moduleName = "Sheet12" # Modify as needed
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(path)
try:
    wb.VBProject.VBComponents(moduleName).CodeModule.AddFromString(macro)
    print(f"Insert code into {moduleName}")
except:
    print(f"Can't found module {moduleName}")
wb.Close(True)
xl.Quit()
```

If you prefer to use a VBA way:

- Loop through all `VBComponents` to locate the  module.

```
path = r"D:/temp/deneme.xlsm"
moduleName = "Sheet1" # Modify as needed
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(path)
found = False
for vbc in wb.VBProject.VBComponents:
    if vbc.name == moduleName:
        found = True
        break
if found:
    vbc.CodeModule.AddFromString(macro)
    print(f"Insert code into {moduleName}")
else:
    print(f"Can't found module {moduleName}")
wb.Close(True)
xl.Quit()
```